# HTTP request through proxy in Erlang

Tags: proxy, erlang

I would like to write a generic server that could spawn many HTTP/HTTPS requests through a proxy, in a manner: every HTTP request through different proxy. How can I do it ? It seems that it is possible to tunnel all traffic through some one, specific proxy, but I would like to change proxy on every request (ex. reading from file containing lines like "109.121.144.17:8008").

Does anybody know how to do it ? I tried standard httpc module but I cannot find info how to use it in the way I would like to.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [ibrowse](https://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse)? You can specify the proxy settings on each request like:

```
7> ibrowse:send_req("http://www.google.com/", [], get, [], 
                 [{proxy_user, "XXXXX"},
                  {proxy_password, "XXXXX"},
                  {proxy_host, "proxy"},
                  {proxy_port, 8080}], 1000).
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I tried to use ibrowse but the problem arises when I am trying pass IP number as a proxy_host. I get badarg error. How to do it ?